# Inject config/constant from html

Tags: angularjs

I have this problem, that it would be easier for me to *inject* some configuration to my Angular app from html. What I'm thinking about is something like:

In HTML:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" my-config="ABC">
</body>
```

So later I could *convert it* to a constant, so I can easier reuse the value across rest of the app. Something like:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .constant('MY_CONFIG', /** the value would become what was set in HTML */);
```

Would something like that be possible? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved that differently. In the end of my `<body>`, after all *js* files are loaded I'm just setting the value:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <!-- [...] -->

    <script>
        angular
          .module('MyApp')
          .constant('MY_CONFIG', 'testing.config');
    </script>
</body>
```